# Resynch latest workouts

Tags: ipod-nano, health.app

I just plugged in my iPod Nano to upload my last few workouts to Nike. When iTunes started it said there was a new version that I agreed to upgrade to, and part of the upgrade required quitting iTunes. Now my last 4 workouts are not uploaded to Nike+. Is it possible to get those workouts uploaded, or are they lost forever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up contacting Nike and they were able to add the basic details to their site. It didn't have all the details, but the overall time and distance were added. I would guess that there isn't a way to resend a workout if it doesn't upload right.